# Converting a particular array to an object

Tags: php

I'm looking for an elegant approach to convert `$array` to `$object`.

If `$array` contains `Array ( [0] => en=english [1] => fr=french )` the resulting `$object` should contain `stdClass Object ( [en] => english [fr] => french )`

The most elegant approach would be the one that uses the least variable names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use [`parse_ini_string`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-string.php)

```
$object = (object) parse_ini_string(join(PHP_EOL, $array));
```

As long as all your values are `key=val` this will work.

All rules for ini files apply, meaning it will choke on `foo=bar=baz` but not on `foo="bar=baz"` because ini files allow additional `=` when it's put into quotes.

---

If you are not on PHP 5.3 yet, you can use [`parse_ini_file`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php) to accept the joined array contents from a [data stream wrapper](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.data.php). This requires `allow_url_include` to be enabled in your php.ini though.

```
$object = (object) parse_ini_file(
    'data:text/plain,' . urlencode(join(PHP_EOL, $array))
);
```

In both cases, the output is the same.

Comment: Brilliant! That's exactly the kind of answer I've been hoping for. Btw, is passing PHP_EOL necessary? It seems to be working with just the one argument - `join($array)`.

Comment: @Emanuil Are you sure? It doesnt work for me when I omit the `PHP_EOL`. In an ini file, new entries are separated by new lines, so I'd say you have to have it.

Comment: @Gordon, No, you are right - it doesn't. I missed that because I tested it on a single item array at first. I commented hasty. I apologize.

Comment: @Gordon, Thanks for adding a before PHP 5.3 approach! It's very nice to know as my server runs an earlier version. Would it be a bad idea to define a `parse_ini_string` function using `if (!function_exists('parse_ini_string')){ function parse_ini_string ...` in order for my code to work on versions prior to 5.3?

Answer (score 4):

Should do it:

```
$object = new stdClass();

$array = array('en=english','fr=french', 'foo=bar=baz');
foreach($array as $item){
    list($name, $value) = explode('=', $item, 2);
    $object->$name = $value;
}
```

Comment: Won't work if you have an element "foo=bar=test". Although, the example in the question doesn't have such a case.

Comment: That's my bad for mis-copying the example! I've corrected that.

Comment: I know, but by the time I edited it you'd already posted yours and I would have basically given the same example, which didn't seem fair. This way there's some variety :)

Comment: could add the third argument to explode to limit the number of splits. That would handle foo=bar=baz

Comment: Beautiful! I didn't know explode() had a $limit parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Best way to do this:

```
<?php
$arr = array('en=english','test=blaat','foo=bar=test');


foreach ($arr as $item)
{
  $opts = explode('=',$item);
  $name = array_shift($opts);
  $obj->$name = implode('=',$opts);
}

print_r($obj);
```

Returns:

```
stdClass Object  
(  
    [en] => english  
    [test] => blaat  
    [foo] => bar=test  
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this

```
foreach ($arr as $item)
{
   $things=explode('=',$item);
   $newArray[$things[0]]=$things[1];
}
$obj=(object) $newArray;
```

Comment: Same issue here: Won't work if you have an element "foo=bar=test".

Comment: @Pelle ten Cate: As OP did not posted this type of example. The answer is completely based on shown examples.

Comment: You have a point there. Though, if the example would be exactly the only case he wanted to deal with, just setting the values manually would be even faster. :)

Comment: @Pelle ten Cate: Nice talk, But I have a small common sense so I know foo=bar indicates that foo is act as a variable and bar act as a value. There is not meaning of third thing "test"